# Yamaha fz700 brake and headlights problem

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, headlight, wiring, yamaha

Recently bought a Yamaha fz700 bike. Headlights don't work whatsoever, checked fuses, bulbs, and I found that wires aren't getting any power. Flipping the Hi/Lo beam switch doesn't change anything either. Also the brake lights work, and the foot pedal lights them up, but the hand lever doesn't. I m trying to stay away from disassembling the whole wiring harness since its kinda messy, that would be a last resort, but I was wondering if there's anything else I could do to troubleshoot it. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track. Do the turn signals work? Also, what year of bike is it?

Comment: Iqbal - please don't repost your question unless there is something new. This is a duplicate.

Comment: Fixed the turn signals, lol, my bad though